# Cannot change the width of MaterialButton

Tags: flutter, dart

For the life of me, I can't figure the button width problem. I have no idea what the width of the button is currently, but I can tell you that it's not decreasing when I tell it to. It stays the exact same, and it doesn't even increase when increasing the minWidth value.

```dart
Material(
  child: MaterialButton(
     minWidth: 20.0,
     child: Icon(Icons.add),
     color: Colors.blue,
   ),
)
```

Comment: It depends on the context at which you are using the Material Button. I guess you remove Material Widget.

Answer (score 1):

You've to add *onPressed* property to MaterialButton, otherwise *onPressed* will be null and the button will be disabled by default.

Source: [Flutter Doc/MaterialButton/onPressed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/onPressed.html)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Sebastian Alejandro

> onPressed will be null and the button will be disabled by default

It could be the background color of your layout which is not making it properly visible when it's disabled. Add `disabledColor` property

```
MaterialButton(
        disabledColor: Colors.black26,
        minWidth: 160.0,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        color: Colors.blue,
      );
```

**Edit:**
Considering your background is white

`minWidth: 160.0` with no `disabledColor`

[image: screenshot 1]

`minWidth: 160.0` with `disabledColor: Colors.black26`

[image: screenshot 2]

`minWidth: 260.0` with `disabledColor: Colors.black26`

[image: screenshot 3]

Comment: Sorry for the very long reply. Still haven't got this issue resolved. Tried the solution you and the above user pointed out, still no change. Any other ideas?

Comment: Look at the screenshots I added.